# sed command issue with string replacement

Tags: string, bash, macos, shell, sed

I'm having a *weird* problem with the sed command.

I have a script that take a c file, copy it X times and then replace the name of the functions inside it by adding number to the name.

For example:

```
originalFile.c contains these functions check0, check1 check2
```

The script will generate those file:

```
originalFile1.c: check0 check1 check2
originalFile2.c: check3 check4 check5
originalFile3.c: check6 check7 check8
... and so on.
```

Now the problem... If I generate enough files so the number goes up to 10,20 or more I noticed something in the name of the function. The first function of the file is renamed incorrectly but the other are corrects. For example:

```
originalFileX.c: __check165__ check16 check17
...
originalFileZ.c: __check297__ __check298__ check29 -> in this file 2 names are incorrects.
```

Also, If I print the name with *echo* everything is correct. Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Here is my script (I run it under OSX):

```
#!/bin/bash


NUMCHECK=3

# $1: filename
# $2: number of function in the file
# $3: number of function I want to generate
# $4: function basename
function replace_name() {
  FILE_NUM=$((($3+($2-1))/$2))
  TMP=0
  for (( i=1; i<$FILE_NUM+1; i++ ))
  do
    cp $1.mm test/$1$i.mm

    for (( j=0; j<$2; j++ ))
    do
      OLDNAME="$4$j"
      NEWNAME="$4$TMP"
      echo $OLDNAME:$NEWNAME
      sed -i "" "s/$OLDNAME/$NEWNAME/g" test/$1$i.mm
      TMP=$(($TMP+1))
    done
   done
}

replace_name check $NUMCHECK 60 check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre doing 3 runs of the `sed` in each file. Just imagine the following

```
sed -i  s/check0/check150/g test/check51.mm
sed -i  s/check1/check151/g test/check51.mm
sed -i  s/check2/check152/g test/check51.mm
```

The

- `s/check0/check150/g` changes the `check0` to `check150` - ok
- `s/check1/check151/g` will change the previous `check150` to `check15150` (because it finds the `check1` string in the `check150` too, from the previous step).
- etc...

You need more precisely define your regex. because here isn't any example input, can't help more.

Comment: @pyknite things happens :) don't worry. :) Just take a break... :) :)

Comment: @pyknite ... and meantime you could read the: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :D